# Creating DB context as impersonated user throws UnauthorizedAccessException - EF 6.4.4

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, impersonation

I started an application as lokal user (UserA). The DBContext will be created as different user (Domain UserB) using an impersonation context:

```
using (windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    ...
}
```

Creating the DBContext throws an exception that the user.config file (of UserB) cannot be read.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Users\UserB\AppData\Local\<appName>\0.0.0.0\user.config' is denied. (C:\Users\UserB\AppData\Local\<appName>\0.0.0.0\user.config) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\UserB\AppData\Local\<appName>\0.0.0.0\user.config' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticOpenStreamForRead(String streamName)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName, Boolean assertPermissions)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(InternalConfigEventArgs e)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(String configPath, BaseConfigurationRecord configRecord)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection..ctor(DbContext context, String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)
```

The file access does not run within the impersonation context.

Is there another way to create a DBContext as a different user?

```
EF version: EF6 (6.4.4)
Database Provider: SqlServer
Operating system: Win10
IDE: Visual Studio 2019
```

Comment: AFAIK (and I might be wrong), Win32 security impersonation is not supported by EF (though this particular issue probably can be worked-around by reading the connection-string yourself), especially if you use any `async` methods as those cause code to run on different threads.

Comment: Also, why is your `DbContext` type named `MyEntityFrameworkContainer`? Your `DbContext` is not a "container" (especially not a DI container). The standard naming convention in .NET is for subclasses to use their supertype as a name suffix, so you should rename it to `MyEntityFrameworkDbContext (though the "`EntityFramework`" part is entirely redundant, so just `MyDbContext` is sufficient).

Comment: "The file access does not run within the impersonation context." - **you should fix that then**: because the .NET CLR loads assemblies on-demand there's a risk here that during impersonation the CLR will fail to load some assembly/DLL from your program's `bin` directory, which will make your program crash. If you change your impersonation code to use **combine** your initial permissions (including read-access on those DLLs and the `app.config` file) with the impersonated user's permissions then you won't need to change anything. However as I don't know how to do that I can't post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible workaround to avoid reading the .config files:

```
SqlConnection connection;
using (windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();

}

using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(connection, false))
{
    ...
}

using (windowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```